# Heroku Golang Deployment

Tags: go, heroku

Here is my workspace

**$GOPATH/src/github.com/ulukma/weder-deploy**

I have Procfile

**web:weder-deploy**

and also I have Godeps folder.

And I pushed my app to Heroku successfully. But when I am trying to open it I get an error

> 2018-09-06T22:49:31.839903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=weaderapp.herokuapp.com request_id=64fd68c8-3012-4bc6-9a00-eedaacbb799c fwd="64.30.109.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-09-06T22:49:32.590403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=weaderapp.herokuapp.com request_id=d962d485-85f9-44a7-9214-da7922495656 fwd="64.30.109.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale your app to at least one web dyno:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

This will boot one dyno (container) running your `weder-deploy` command, allowing requests to go through that container and resolving that specific error.